# Problem with box-shadow on div containing table(height problem)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, css

Hey guys I have a box shadow on a div.

```
    #overviewDiv {

        -webkit-box-shadow:0 40px 40px -40px #AAA;
        -moz-box-shadow:0 40px 40px -40px #AAA;
        box-shadow:0 40px 40px -40px #AAA;

    }

<div id="overviewDiv" >       
    <br />

    <table class="display" id="pkgLineTable"  >
        <thead> 
            <tr>        
                <th style="width:120px">&{'views.overview.location'}</th>                 
                <th style="width:200px">&{'views.overview.linename'}</th>
                <th style="width:200px">&{'views.overview.description'}</th> 
                <th style="width:200px">&{'views.overview.linestatus'}</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

The box shadow looks fine normally with 10 rows or so but if not it doesn't display right.

[image]

In this picture the shadow is way under the table.  I'm not sure what to do to fix this.  Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/jZvqe/7/

Comment: if you can create a minimal example on jsfiddle.net we can help you better

Comment: Sure

http://jsfiddle.net/jZvqe/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't understand exactly what is the problem, it might help to know that datatables creates a div with class dataTables_wrapper that wraps around the table (i think it goes between your div and the table in your case) and  has a min_height of 302px and an height of 302px. The creator of datatables says that he does this to avoid clutttering, but this has some weird effects when you have little rows.

so i ususally add this in my css:

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
   _height: 102px;
   min-height: 102px;
}
```

Be careful to declare this in a css file imported after the demo_table.css.

I've edited this fiddle by taking away some rows: http://jsfiddle.net/jZvqe/8/ --> you have tro plobem

Added the CSS lines: http://jsfiddle.net/jZvqe/9/ --> the drop shadow is okay

Answer (score 0):

It seems that overviewDiv somehow has a min-height. What is the br tag doing there anyway, perhaps this forces the div to grow? Hard to know with so little info...

Comment: There is an addedd div that has min-height of 302px that it's created by datatables, it shows only when the table has very little rows.